# Power sharing with Li-po charger

Tags: battery-charging, low-power, lithium-polymer

I'm working on a Li-po charger with power sharing. I had a look at [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20230327184241/https://blog.zakkemble.net/a-lithium-battery-charger-with-load-sharing/) which shows a circuit like this:

[image: Source]

I may well be misunderstanding, but I can't see how the MOSFET Q1 is ever switched on. It looks like Vgs can be either zero (when USB is not connected) or Vgs can be the D1 voltage drop, which will be below the threshold voltage. So is the Q1 body diode in fact the only reason it works?

I recreated the circuit like this, and it does work, but the voltage drop across Q1 does seem to indicate that the body diode is all that's conducting (i.e. Q1 is not switched on).

[image: Original]

Given that, would it make sense to just use a second [Schottky diode with a low voltage drop](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bat20j.pdf)? Like this:

[image: Dual Schottky Diodes]

And, more radically, given that the power consumption of the system is very low (average 3-4 mA), could I just get away with this:

[image: VBAT only]

Or does anyone have any better suggestions or sources that I can look at?

Comment: Read this [application note](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01149c.pdf) to understand how the loading sharing circuit work. When the power is supply via VBUS, the Q1 is actual off, and power is supplying to the load via D1, when the charging IC is charing the battery without load. When VBUS is not present, the gate of Q1 is pull to the ground and Q1 is on, the VBAT is feeding the load.... If your load sharing circuit is not working, it probably that you had the wrong type of MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks - it is working - the MOSFET I am using is this one (DMP3099L-13)

https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP3099L.pdf

I was confused about how the Vs could go high, I didn't realize the body diode is responsible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to apply a load to charger while it is charging the battery. Otherwise it may not stop charging the battery at correct current so it will always overcharge the battery.

You might get away with the schottky diodes, but the FET will likely have better isolation or leakage current properties. As long as correct FET is used, it should work.

Comment: So.. the FET can be switched on? I don't see how...

Comment: Ah, I _think_ I understand - the voltage at Q1 source is 'bootstrapped' by the VBAT flowing through the body diode, right?